# How to get or plot a single curve in multivariate polynomial Regression in Python (Expected shape would be like 'S-shaped curve)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, regression

Is there any way to get a single curve from multivariate polynomial Regression? I know simple polynomial Regression with one feature column and one target column. But in this case, I had 6 features. So for the sake of simplicity, I have reduced the features column to 3 (Date,  temperature, moisture). And target column (growth_state) is still one.
But when I plot the data. I am getting a pretty weird multiple lines/shape instead of a single 'S-shaped curve. A sample of data from the original dataset is shown below. (Note: For now, I have only 160 data points. Is it possible to make Polynomial Regression with these less data points?)

```
   dateInDays   Temperature     moist  growth_state
82  112         13.6086        0.3757    2
83  112        13.6086        0.3757     2
84  108        11.3914        0.3907     6
85  82         7.6843         0.3729     2
86  82         7.6843         0.3729     2

#modelling
X = df.iloc[:, 0:3].values
y = df.iloc[:, -1].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)

lin_reg_1 = LinearRegression()
lin_reg_1.fit(X_poly, y)

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X[:,0], lin_reg_1.predict(X_poly), color = 'blue') 
# plt.scatter(X[:,0], lin_reg_1.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X)), color = 'green')
plt.title('Multivariate Polynomial Regression')
plt.xlabel('Date Range')
plt.ylabel('Growth Stage')
plt.show()
```

[image]

-Expected plot
[image]

-After slight change in code from X to X_poly in lin_reg_1.fit(X_poly, y)
[image] . Note: This plot is obtained only after sorting the dataset

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you for your time

Edited the code a little bit:

1)After @Derek O's suggestion. It was my mistake while writing the code instead of X_poly, I wrote X in line =>lin_reg_1.fit(X, y). which I have corrected to =>lin_reg_1.fit(X_poly, y). Now we are getting at least a decent result. But again I am not able to get the expected shape, which I have shown above in a handwritten image.

2)Now, I have also added the required dataset ([data_link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10LexZr1q73NIJIR_qdhD66PD4352mZym/view)) by which anyone can test the code

Answer (score 2):

When I try to run your code it throws the following error for me:

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 3 is different from 10)
```

Since you trained the polynomial regression on 3 features, you need to pass something that has the same second dimension as X. In your example, X has shape (5,3) so to get predictions, when you call `lin_reg_1.predict(X_pred)`, X_pred needs to have a shape `(n,3)`

Also keep in mind that when you use `plt.plot(X[:,0], lin_reg_1.predict(X_poly), color = 'blue')` to construct your trendline, this will draw lines between all of the coordinates in the order your supply them, so if you only use a few values to draw this trendline and you don't put them in order, you're not going to get a curve.

Here is an example I made up where the data is approximately a degree two polynomial with respect to the 3 features, and there are enough points to draw a curve. Hopefully this helps.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# df = pd.read_clipboard()
size = 20
x0 = np.linspace(0,50,size)
x1 = np.linspace(0,10,size)
x2 = np.linspace(0,20,size)

np.random.seed(42)
noise = 50*np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=size)

target = x0 + 0.5*x1**2 + 2*x2**2 + noise
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x0':x0,
    'x1':x1,
    'x2':x2,
    'y':target
})

#modelling
X = df.iloc[:, 0:3].values
y = df.iloc[:, -1].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)
poly_reg.fit(X_poly,y)

lin_reg_1 = LinearRegression()
lin_reg_1.fit(X, y)

lin_reg_2 = LinearRegression()
lin_reg_2.fit(X_poly,y)

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], y, color = 'red')

X_pred = np.array([x0,x1,x2]).T
plt.plot(X_pred[:,0], lin_reg_1.predict(X_pred), color = 'blue') 
plt.plot(X_pred[:,0], lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X_pred)), color = 'green')
plt.title('Multivariate Polynomial Regression')
plt.xlabel('Date Range')
plt.ylabel('Growth Stage')
plt.show()
```

[image]